# Doing *apply on a list of list in R

Tags: r, list, vectorization

I have a list of vectors in R (`featuresList`), of this form:

```
[[2]]
  [1] 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
 [93] 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
[[3]]
  [1] 0.64285714 0.74285714 0.78571429 0.57142857 0.60000000 0.68571429 0.67142857 0.64285714 0.74285714 0.71428571 0.57142857 0.42857143 0.72857143 0.54285714 0.64285714 0.65714286
 [17] 0.57142857 0.70000000 0.47142857 0.64285714 0.47142857 0.70000000 0.57142857 0.62857143 0.57142857 0.78571429 0.61428571 0.57142857 0.50000000 0.57142857 0.74285714 0.62857143
```

I have write this `for` to sum each element of one list with its corresponding element on other list. In the example above, The list `[[2]]` has two list, I want to sum each element of this list with the elements in the list `[[3]]`. So, I would sum the 1 in `[[2]][1]` with the number in `[[3]][1]`, which is a `0.64285714`, the result is `1.64285714`.

At first thought I came up with this loop:

```
features <- 0
  for(i in seq_along(featuresList)){
    if(!(is.null(featuresList[[i]])))
      features<-features+ unlist(featuresList[[i]])
  }
```

And does work right:

```
[1] 1.6428571 0.7428571 0.7857143 1.5714286 1.6000000 0.6857143 1.6714286 1.6428571 1.7428571 0.7142857 1.5714286 1.4285714 0.7285714 1.5428571 0.6428571 1.6571429 1.5714286 0.7000000
[19] 1.4714286 1.6428571 1.4714286 0.7000000 1.5714286 1.6285714 1.5714286 0.7857143 1.6142857 1.5714286 1.5000000 1.5714286 0.7428571 1.6285714 1.6142857 0.7857143 1.5285714 1.5714286
```

It is summing each element of the first list of vectors with the corresponding elements of the second list of vectors. But I have tried for days to re write this code using *apply with no luck.

Could anybody give a hint of how to do it?

Comment: I don't see a list of lists in your question. I see two vectors in a list.

Comment: @Roland, sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can just add the vectors in the list - without using `*apply` functions:

```
featuresList[[2]] + featuresList[[3]]
#[1] 1.6428571 0.7428571 0.7857143 1.5714286 1.6000000 0.6857143 1.6714286 1.6428571 1.7428571 0.7142857 1.5714286 1.4285714 0.7285714
```

If we want to add all vectors in the list, we can use `Reduce()`, as suggested by @akrun:

```
Reduce("+", featuresList)
#[1] 2.642857 1.742857 1.785714 2.571429 2.600000 1.685714 2.671429 2.642857 2.742857 1.714286 2.571429 2.428571 1.728571
```

This will return the sum of all the vectors stored in the list (note that in this case `featuresList[[1]]` is a (recycled) vector containing only `1`).

I have used a subset of your data:

```
featuresList <- list(1, c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), c(0.64285714, 
0.74285714, 0.78571429, 0.57142857, 0.6, 0.68571429, 0.67142857, 
0.64285714, 0.74285714, 0.71428571, 0.57142857, 0.42857143, 0.72857143))
```

Comment: But the problem is that the lengh of the list is larger than 2, I mean, here you are using [[2]] and [[3]], but in practice, I could have any size. So I want to generalize it to a list of lists of length n. Thing of it as a matrix (nx386) where n is the number of list that I have, and 386 is the size of each sublist (Which is indeed fixed)

Comment: @akrun, but I do not want to reduce to a number, I want as many numbers as elements in the sublists.

Comment: or `colSums(do.call(rbind, featuresList[2:3]))` which should be faster than `Reduce` for many list elements. These values should probably be in a matrix anyway.

Comment: This is indeed a nice alternative, @Roland